# Creating a dynamic sql query using variables and in some cases their values (with joins)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I need to create a dynamic SQL query that changes based on different arguments/variables existence and value:

So, I have something like this:

def create_query(user=None, max=None, list=None)

```
qs = 'SELECT N.status'

if user: 
    qs = qs.join('U.email')

qs = join('from notes as N)'

if user: 
  qs = 'LEFT JOIN users AS U on N.user_id=U.id'

if max:
  qs = qs.join('where max=') + max

if list:

  qs = qs.join('where fame_values in list')

....
```

I have around 20 variables that can change the query, so I'm looking for something more pythonic(like list comprehensions with conditions) but for strings

Comment: Do not do data concatenation like `qs.join('where max=') + max
` since this is a security hole and will also impact application scalability.  Use a bind variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a function which create the query according to the arguments you pass to it.
Consider the following example:

```
def create_query(user, max_value = None):
    query = 'SELECT N.status'+ (' U.email' if user else ' ') + ' from notes as N' + (' LEFT JOIN users AS U on N.user_id=U.id' if user else ' ') + (' where max={}'.format(max_value) if max_value else " ") 
    return query

query = create_query(user=True,max_value=10)
# SELECT N.status U.email from notes as N LEFT JOIN users AS U on N.user_id=U.id where max=10
query = create_query(user=False)
# SELECT N.status  from notes as N 
query = create_query(user=True)
# SELECT N.status U.email from notes as N LEFT JOIN users AS U on N.user_id=U.id
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with python , i suggest to build the query
inside your code , and connects to the database with cx_Oracle
(or other modules, if you have a different database)

if you really want to do it in pure sql, 
what you need to do is to preform a master join of everything ,
and use case to show the desired data you wish.

```
case when x then y
when b then c
else null end case1,
case2 when x then t
when g then c
else null end case2
from a join b join c join...
```

some examples for that exactly you wish to do will be helpful..

Comment: based on received arguments/variables I need to join none or up to 3 tables, and have multiple where clauses

Comment: you need to create all the 20 options of outcomes , and join them into 1 table in an inner join , so only the outcome that goes with the data will not be null,
and just query that table , but for dynamic queryies , i would use python instead to query the data, it is much easier for more then 2-3 options..